# Segmentation fault with sscanf

Tags: c

I am writing a small C program to test a concept and I am having some problems. Firstly, here is all of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char one[] = "Figure A 200 200 =\0";
char two[] = "Figure B 300 200 =\0";

int main(void)
{
  char buffero[300];
  char buffert[300];
  memset(buffero, 0, sizeof(buffero));
  memset(buffert, 0, sizeof(buffert));

  int * doubleo = 0;
  int * doublet = 0;

  sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ",buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);
  printf("%s %s %d %d", buffero, buffert, *doubleo, *doublet);

  memset(buffero, 0, sizeof(buffero));
  memset(buffert, 0, sizeof(buffert));

  sscanf(two, "%s %s %d %d ", buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);
  printf("%s %s %d %d", buffero, buffert, *doubleo, *doublet);
};
```

It's become slightly convoluted with some of the fixes I have attempted to implement but not all that horribly.

It compiles, however when I run it, I get a segmentation fault.

GDB reports:

```
#3  0x0000000000400683 in main () at mis_test.c:15
15    sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ",buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);
```

Can someone give a bit of insight here? I am rather new to C an I KNOW it's a very very simple problem thats staring me right in the face but I can't seem to get it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `double` pointers are NULL. they need to be valid addressed of int values. change them to `int` and pass their *addresses* into the sscanf call ex: `&doubleo`

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are using int pointers for which you haven't allocated memory.

```
 int * doubleo = 0;
 int * doublet = 0;
```

You can simply use two integers:

```
 int doubleo = 0;
 int doublet = 0;
```

and then call sscanf with `&` as sscanf expects pointers to the integers:

```
  sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ",buffero, buffert, &doubleo, &doublet);
```

Note that you don't need to null terminate the string yourself. It's done by the compiler for you.

Answer (score 0):

For format specifier `%d` `sscanf` expects pointers that point to recipient objects of type `int`. You supplied pointers that point nowhere (null pointers). This is what is causing the crash.

If you insist on using explicit pointers, first you have to make sure that they point to valid `int` objects

```
int io, it;

int * doubleo = &io;
int * doublet = &it;
```

`sscanf` will read the data into `io` and `it` objects

```
sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ", buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);
```

Of course, there 's no real need for these explicit pointers here. You can just get rid of `doubleo` and `doublet` entirely and do

```
sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ", buffero, buffert, &io, &it);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char one[] = "Figure A 200 200 =\0";
char two[] = "Figure B 300 200 =\0";

int main(void)
{
   char buffero[300];
   char buffert[300];
   memset(buffero, 0, sizeof(buffero));
   memset(buffert, 0, sizeof(buffert));

   int doubleo = 0;
   int doublet = 0;

   sscanf(one, "%s %s %d %d ",buffero, buffert, &doubleo, &doublet);
   printf("%s %s %d %d", buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);

   memset(buffero, 0, sizeof(buffero));
   memset(buffert, 0, sizeof(buffert));

   sscanf(two, "%s %s %d %d ", buffero, buffert, &doubleo, &doublet);
   printf("%s %s %d %d", buffero, buffert, doubleo, doublet);
};
```

Or allocate memory for *doubleo and *doublet